# Merge Changesets in the same branch TFS

Tags: tfs

I have some business reasons for wanting to do this but I won't get into those. Basically I have a Team Project with a single branch(I know this is bad) that I have been working on for 6 years now. It has a large number of change sets. I would like to merge first couple thousand change sets into a single one. Is this possible?

All the information on merging change sets seems to be focused on multiple branch situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which you mean is more likely changeset **compression**. Just like using `git squash commit` command to clean up local commit histories.

Unfortunately, this is **impossible**. For now TFS can only merge continuous changesets or single changesets. If this can be done how to handle  the changeset history.

> [TFS to merge multiple, non-continuous changesets.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2638075-tfs-to-merge-multiple-non-continuous-changesets)
>
> Thanks for the feedback on this idea. We have reviewed this feedback
> and determined that we will not be able to complete this suggestion in
> the foreseeable future.
>
> *Matt Mitrik TFS Program Manager*

You may have to create a independent branch for handling this situation.